# Downloading Polygon/Administrative Boundaries using WikiMapia

Tags: polygon, data, download, administrative-boundaries, wikimapia

Is there any way to download administrative boundaries / polygons for a small city through Wikimapia?

I tried to download the boundaries but the results were points not polygons.

I need to download the polygons from wikimapia

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know WikiMapia, but maybe you can find something useful from Natural Earth?

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

At the current date all the maps downloadable from the website are in the public domain.

> *All versions of Natural Earth raster + vector map data found on this website are in the public domain. You may use the maps in any manner, including modifying the content and design, electronic dissemination, and offset printing. The primary authors, Tom Patterson and Nathaniel Vaughn Kelso, and all other contributors renounce all financial claim to the maps and invites you to use them for personal, educational, and commercial purposes.*

Quoted from the terms of use (10th March 2020): https://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/