# Downloading polygons from Wikimapia

Tags: polygon, export, kml, wikimapia

Is there any way to download a polygon from Wikimapia? There's several I created a few years ago and would like to import to Google Earth as .kml.

Most of the answers supplied direct to broken links or old info.

The supplied answer doesn't answer my question: [Downloading Polygon/Administrative Boundaries using WikiMapia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353528/downloading-polygon-administrative-boundaries-using-wikimapia)

It mentions NaturalEarthData which does not have all of Wikimapia's data, mostly just political/natural boundaries. The two blog links in that post are dead links. The GE.KML file is only "points of interest" not polygons. The API link is "Invalid Key", GeoDeg does not have the polygons I'm looking for (very little really), Motomapia does not have the lava flows, OpenStreetMap does not have the polygons at all.

I know Wikimapia appears to be defunct, and all the old answers reflect that.

If anyone is willing to download and share the 17 polygons I need so I can rid myself of Wikimapia that would work too!

Comment: This post may help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353528/downloading-polygon-administrative-boundaries-using-wikimapia

Comment: No, this is specifically talking about points. And the .ge.kml link is broken...

Comment: Also @Padmanabha, I looked at NaturalEarthData, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't import a lot of the user made edits, and it's more generic political/natural data. It's not gonna have the lava flow boundaries I'm looking for.

Comment: If you think that the duplicate is not valid then I recommend starting your question (by editing it) to include a link to the proposed duplicate and explain why it and its answers do not answer your question.  If you show how you have tried to follow them then it is more likely that reviewers will vote to re-open your improved question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have edited my comment to show the previous answers don't help.

Comment: The link you’ve included is different to the duplicate the community proposed.